# Ambiguous overload even one is more specific

Tags: scala, single-abstract-method

I have two definition of `foo`, and one of them is more supposedly specific

```
def foo(f: java.util.function.ToIntFunction[String]) = println("foo1")
def foo[T](f: String=>T) = println("foo2")
//def foo[T](f: String=>T)(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = println("foo2")    //Does not work either


foo({_: String => 1})            //Should pick foo1, but gives error instead
```

Error is:

```
error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method foo in object Main of type [T](f: String => T)Unit
and  method foo in object Main of type (f: java.util.function.ToIntFunction[String])Unit
```

I also tried the trick of `DummyImplicit` but it still gives the same error. How can I achieve compile time overload when `Int` presents without using reflection?

I am using Scala 2.12 with SAM type support.

---

**Edit**

I hope to get a solution that is not limited to using Java converters, because ToIntFunction interface can be replaced by Scala trait, e.g.

```
trait ToIntFunction[T] { def apply(v: T): Int }
def foo(f: ToIntFunction[String]) = println("foo1")
def foo[T](f: String=>T) = println("foo2")
```

as I think it is a more generic problem for method overload.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. On my machine `foo({_: String => 1})` evaluates to  `"foo2"`

Comment: @MarioGalic Are you using a scala version < 2.12? `{_: String => 1}` requires SAM support (from 2.12) to match traits other than FunctionX. It is supposed to evaluate to `foo1` not `foo2`

Comment: My interpretation of [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#sam-conversion-in-overloading-resolution) is that in Scala 2.12 `Function`-typed arguments take precedence, thus it should evaluate to `foo2`. Note `_: String => 1` is `Function1`

Comment: @MarioGalic You are right. It would match FunctionX. How can I make it match SAM conversion if I provide Int in `X => Int`?

Comment: Why did you think the `ToIntFunction` overload is more specific in the first place?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov because it does not take generic type parameter?

Comment: @texasbruce I could reproduce your issue on Scala 2.13 with Java 10. It seems, that if you pass boxed value, then `foo2` is selected. So this works fine `foo({_: String => Int.box(1)})`.

Comment: I can also reproduce it with Scala 2.13, Java 8.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine with Scala 2.12 `foo({_: String => 1})` evaluates to `foo2`, thus I am unable to reproduce the issue. My interpretation of [SAM conversion in overloading resolution](https://www.scala-lang.org/news/2.12.0/#sam-conversion-in-overloading-resolution) in Scala 2.12 is that `Function`-typed arguments take precedence, thus it should evaluate to `foo2`:

> In order to improve source compatibility, overloading resolution has
>   been adapted to prefer methods with Function-typed arguments over
>   methods with parameters of SAM types.

Note `_: String => 1` is `Function1`. To force it to evaluate to `foo1` try `asJava` from [scala-java8-compat](https://github.com/scala/scala-java8-compat) like so:

```
import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._
foo({_: String => 1}.asJava) // foo1
```

As per Krzysztof Atłasik's comment it is reproducible in Scala 2.13.

Comment: Explicit casting/converting works, but I was wondering if there is any solution to identify when `Int` presents as a special case and select the first one. Of course I could use TypeTag/Manifest, but it is too much overhead and not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution using macro expansion:

```
object Foo {
    import scala.reflect.macros.Context
    import scala.language.experimental.macros

    def foo[T,R](f: T=>R) = macro fooImpl[T,R]

    def fooImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag, R: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)
        (f: c.Expr[T=>R]): c.Expr[Unit] = {
        import c.universe._
        if(c.weakTypeOf[R] == c.weakTypeOf[Int]) {
            reify { println("Int") }
        }
        else {
            reify { println("Not Int") }
        }
    }
}
```

In another file,

```
object Test extends MainApp {
  Foo.foo {_:String => 0}    //expands into a simple println and it prints "Int"
  Foo.foo {_:String => 0d}   //prints "Not Int"
}
```

This is definitely not ideal, but solves the problem. Hope someone can give an answer without using macro.